# Sequence analysis clustering CHI2 EUCLID error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, traminer, sequence-analysis

I am quite new to sequence analysis and trying to identify clusters in an aggregated sequence matrix, focusing on the state duration. However, when using method='CHI2'/'EUCLID' combined with step=1 (not otherwise) I am getting the error:

*Error in if (SCres > currentSCres) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed*

Any ideas why (there are some NaN in the distance matrix, could they result from sequences being of different length)?

What the sequence object and distance matrix looks like
Code:

```
Sequence                                         
1    a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a
2    a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a  
3    a-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-c-c-c
4    a-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e
5    b-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a

Distance matrix
           1         2      3          4
2        NaN                              
3        289.92897   NaN                    
4        141.07472   NaN    263.22855          
5        10.22425    NaN    290.10919  141.44473
```

Code:

```
library(TraMineR) #version 2.0-13
library(WeightedCluster) #version 1.4

SO = seqdef(DAT,right='DEL')
DM = seqdist(SO, method = "CHI2", step=1, full.matrix = F)
FIT = seqpropclust(SO, diss=DM, maxcluster=8, 
      properties=c("state", "duration", "spell.age","spell.dur",
        "transition","pattern", "AFtransition", "AFpattern","Complexity"))
```

Comment: What happens if you only run `SCres > currentSCres`?

Comment: Could you elaborate please.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Please provide a minimum working example. In addition, could you specify the version of TraMineR you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response (and great package). The data is sensitive so I have made up some sequences which seem to recreate the same problem. I hope it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"CHI2"` distance between two sequences *x* and *y* computed by `TraMineR` is the sum of the Chi-squared distance between the state distributions over the successive periods of length `step`. See [Studer and Ritschard (2014, p 8)](http://dx.doi.org/10.12682/lives.2296-1658.2014.33).

This means that for `step=1` a Chi-squared distance is computed at each position. When one of the sequence has void values at some positions (e.g. the last position in your second sequence), the distance cannot be computed for these positions and we get a `NaN` value for the `CHI2` distance between this sequence and any other sequence.

To avoid that, you can use the following workarounds:

1) Set a `step` value large enough to be sure each sequence contains at least one non-void element in each period intervals. For your example, the longest sequences are of length 25. To be sure the last period contains non void elements, you have to set `step=5`.

```
DAT <- c("a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a",
         "a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a",  
         "a-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-c-c-c",
         "a-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e",
         "b-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a-a")
SO <- seqdef(DAT)
DM <- seqdist(SO, method = "CHI2", step=5)
DM
##          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
## [1,] 0.000000 0.000000 4.543441 4.543441 1.030776
## [2,] 0.000000 0.000000 4.543441 4.543441 1.030776
## [3,] 4.543441 4.543441 0.000000 2.028370 4.604927
## [4,] 4.543441 4.543441 2.028370 0.000000 4.604927
## [5,] 1.030776 1.030776 4.604927 4.604927 0.000000
```

2) Drop the columns with void elements:

```
SOdrop <- SO[,1:(ncol(SO)-1)]
SOdrop
DMd <- seqdist(SOdrop, method = "CHI2", step=1)
DMd
##          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
## [1,]  0.00000  0.00000 10.041580 10.041580  2.50000
## [2,]  0.00000  0.00000 10.041580 10.041580  2.50000
## [3,] 10.04158 10.04158  0.000000  4.472136 10.34811
## [4,] 10.04158 10.04158  4.472136  0.000000 10.34811
## [5,]  2.50000  2.50000 10.348108 10.348108  0.00000
```

3) Fill the shorter sequences with missings and consider the missing value as an additional possible state. By default `right='DEL'` in `seqdef`, which creates voids. Here we set `right=NA` to get missing values instead.

```
SOm = seqdef(DAT, right=NA)
DMm = seqdist(SOm, method = "CHI2", step=1, with.missing=TRUE)
DMm
##          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
## [1,]  0.000000  2.738613 10.408330 10.408330  2.500000
## [2,]  2.738613  0.000000 10.527741 10.527741  3.708099
## [3,] 10.408330 10.527741  0.000000  5.477226 10.704360
## [4,] 10.408330 10.527741  5.477226  0.000000 10.704360
## [5,]  2.500000  3.708099 10.704360 10.704360  0.000000
```

Now, the error reported in the question is NOT an error of `seqdist`, but of the `seqpropclust` function from the `WeightedCluster` library. The error is obviously caused by the `NaN` in the dissimilarity matrix.